# emails are comming to gmail and in spam

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I have two issues to solve .

1. In `mystore->configuration->sales->order email copy` when i add
   something@gmail.com email is received (but in spam ).  but when i
   add something@owndomain.co.uk . email is not received not even in
   spam.
2. can we solve this spam issue ?   I am using Magento 2.2.6 , i
   already did reply to path on but something is wrong maybe it is not
   working .

Comment: Your Hosting service provider?

Comment: @samair how did you solve this ? i am also getting email in spam

Comment: using smtp , there must be a plugin for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento by default is using built in `PHP mail()` function to send e-mails. Commonly some important settings are left at their default values in **Magento admin**, and are often overlooked or forgotten.  By default most people are just configuring default mail sending address in Magento, and stop at that.

This will only set the `<from: >` e-mail address in `$additional_headers` field for `mail() function`. This will indeed put a mail from address in recipients inbox to your mail address but if we inspect the mail headers and server logs actual sending e-mail address will be something like `apache@servername.com`. This alone will be reason enough for some **spam** filters to classify that mail as spam since mail-from and envelope-from will be a`pache@servername.com` and `<from:>` headers will be your configured e-mail address.

In this case I’ve used `apache@servername.com` as a “**true**” senders address but this may vary, depending on how your web server is configured.

**Changing**

> System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings >
>   **Set** Return-Path to **YES**

**REVERSE DNS**

- When you’re sending an e-mail from a server inside your domain, make
  sure it has its own IP address and its `hostname` is resolved to that
  IP address.

**‘WHITE’ IP ADDRESS**

- Sometimes your IP address may become blacklisted, if you lost your
  reputation by sending wrong e-mails. After you got a new IP address
  from your provider, it’s recommended not to use this address for at
  least a month. The reason behind this is that your new IP address
  might already be used by someone else before. This 1 month delay lets
  the IP address get cleared and became ‘`white`’.

**[SMTP](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/)**

- A good **solution** is to use **[SMTP server](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/)** to send e-mails in
  Magento. It can be a public one (such as Gmail, Yahoo and so on, if
  you trust them), or your private mail server.

  ---

[RECOMMENDED E-MAIL STRUCTURE IN MAGENTO](https://www.arpatech.com/blog/avoid-sending-spam-emails-in-magento/)

Comment: yes i have tried smpt module by mageplaza but it is not working with magento 2,2,6 i think . it causes error .

Comment: https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_SMTP

Comment: use this for smtp

Answer (score 2):

You can use SMTP module for sending email through Magento. (check Mageplaza SMTP module).

Comment: i have tried it but maybe it is not compatible with magento 2.2.6

Comment: It is compatible with Magento 2.2. You may need the core module of Mageplaza also.

Comment: @SaurabhDwivedi Mageplaza extension will be work for magento 2.3.1 version ?

Comment: @sumeetbajaj, Yes It is working fine in 2.3.1 also. You need add Magplaza core modules also.

Comment: yes it works,great

Answer (score 0):

One important setting in Magento 1 and 2 regarding spam is setting "Yes" for

```
System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings > Set Return-Path
```

The name of this setting is a bit misleading: With this setting to "Yes" Magento sets envelope-from of all mails it generates to the configured return address of the specific transactional mail.

With this setting on "No" envelope-from is set by the server and thus header-from != envelop-from. This leads many receiving mail servers to mark the message as spam.